# Full window HTML5 Canvas "white noise" animation lags on Android Firefox

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I've made a white noise animation in javascript/HTML5 canvas to cover the whole browser window.

I'm using an offscreen square canvas equal to half the browser window size for the source image:

```
var doc = document;
h = Math.max(
    doc.body.scrollHeight, doc.documentElement.scrollHeight,
    doc.body.offsetHeight, doc.documentElement.offsetHeight,
    doc.body.clientHeight, doc.documentElement.clientHeight
);
w = Math.max(
    doc.body.scrollWidth, doc.documentElement.scrollWidth,
    doc.body.offsetWidth, doc.documentElement.offsetWidth,
    doc.body.clientWidth, doc.documentElement.clientWidth
);

blocksize = Math.floor(h / 2);
tilesize = Math.floor(blocksize / 8);

tiles_w = Math.floor(w / tilesize);
tiles_h = Math.floor(h / tilesize); 

var colors = [
    [255, 255, 255, 255],
    [220, 220, 220, 255],
    [170, 170, 170, 255],
    [120, 120, 120, 255],
    [0, 0, 0, 255]
    ];

offBlockCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
offBlockContext = offBlockCanvas.getContext("2d");
offBlockCanvas.width = blocksize;
offBlockCanvas.height = blocksize;

var imageData = offBlockContext.getImageData(0, 0, blocksize, blocksize);
var imagedata = imageData.data;

for (i = 0; i < blocksize * blocksize * 4; i+=4) {
    var pixelcolor = parseInt(Math.random() * 8)

    if (pixelcolor > 3) {
        pixelcolor = 4;
    }

    imagedata[i] = colors[pixelcolor][0];
    imagedata[i + 1] = colors[pixelcolor][1];
    imagedata[i + 2] = colors[pixelcolor][2];
    imagedata[i + 3] = colors[pixelcolor][3];
}

offBlockContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
```

Then randomly clip tiles of 1/8 of the offscreen square canvas to blit directly to the onscreen canvas. The result looks nice; not tiled at all.

```
function snowloop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(snowloop);    

    for (i = 0; i <= tiles_h; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= tiles_w; j++) {
            var next_x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (blocksize - tilesize))
            var next_y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (blocksize - tilesize))
            context.drawImage(offBlockCanvas, next_x, next_y, tilesize, tilesize, j * tilesize, i * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize);
        }
    }


}
```

It's running very smoothly in all browsers on my linux and windows (45-60 FPS), and on Opera and Chrome on my Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini (Android 4.1 Jelly Bean). *But when I run it on Firefox (v34.0) on the Android I only get 5 FPS or so.*

The full code for the animation is on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/lash/f9mdoods/3/

Comment: Could be a HW/FF problem, but try to pre-scale the source image, then tile/blit 1:1 without using the scale parameters of drawImage. You can optionally try to turn off image smoothing (ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false) to force nearest neighbor interpolation during scale (may need moz-prefix with that). Though with a baseline of 5 fps I doubt it will give you an extreme burst, but it also depends on the implementation so you'll never know...